# convert python objects to string

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I have different python classes and I want to convert instances of these classes to ascii strings.Suppose that I have the following objects:

```
class A:
    name = "A"
    field = 2
    x = "a"

class B:
    name = "b"
    item = "c"

a = A()
b = B()
```

I want a function like `serialize()` which converts the objects as follows:

```
serialize(a) # results "A2a"
serialize(b) # results "bc"
```

I don't want to write a serialization function for every classe, I want to have a function capable of serializing all classes. One way is to use the `dir()` function to get a list of object attributes and then create a string out of them, but the `dir()` function does not return the attributes in the same order that they are defined. For example calling `dir(a)` would return `['__doc__', '__module__', 'filed', 'name', 'x']`, and I cannot find out which attribute is defined first in the class.

Thanks.

Comment: You can overload the __str_ or __repr__ magic methods however you want inside the class, or define your own class method to return the string representation however you like

Comment: would defining a `serialize` method in each of these classes be a valid option?

Comment: It would be best if I can do it in a general function that can serialize every class. I don't want to write a serialization function for every class!

Answer (score 2):

You can override [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) function for print Object the desired way:

```
class A:
    name = "A"
    field = 2
    x = "a"

    def __repr__(self):
        return A.name + str(A.field) + A.x
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't want to write a serialize function for every class. I need a general serialization function that can serialize all classes.

Comment: @ayyoobimani Then you need a parent class for all classes and you need to define a serializer for the parent class.

Comment: @ARMAN and how does the serializer know about the order that the fields are added to the class?

Comment: @ayyoobimani actually it doesn't, you should consider naming attributes the same way and same order in child classes in order to define the serializer general.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create methods in your classes:
ON behalf to put the value in the class the best can be to pass argument of class A during the call%

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, field, x) :
    self.name = name
    self.field = field
    self.x = x

   def serialize(self) :
       return f"{self.name}{self.field}{self.x}"

#main:
a=A(name="a", field="field", x="x") 
result=a.serialize()
print(result)
```